# How to increase Rakshasa's Graces?

Tags: experience-points, exalted, attributes, exalted-2e

According to the Fair Folk books, characters start with Graces equal to their virtues. There are also charms for creating new Graces for the Fair Folk, but they start at level 1. However, I can't find any rules on how to increase the Graces - do they increase by experience expenditure (if so, what's the cost?), are they re-forged into higher level artefacts, or is it something else?

Any edition is fine.

Comment: no info on 3rd ed rakshasa available yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graces can be raised with Bonus Points and Experience Points like any other stat. I don't have the books at the moment so I can't give you page numbers but [this site](http://www.brilliantdisaster.net/dif/ExaltedCheatsheet.html) lists their prices in 2e as:

Major Grace:    3bp (-1 for Commoner) or    [Rating]*3 xp.

Minor Grace:    5bp or  [Rating]*6 xp.

Heart Grace:    20xp to Heart 4. (Only available at +200xp)

As I recall the Charms to create Graces are to give *other* beings, not to add to your own.

I would check out the [Scroll of Errata/Exalted 2.5](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product_info.php?products_id=84593)  PDF, I recall there was a *Tonne* of changes to the Fair Folk in there.

Comment: Upvoted just for the errata recommendation. So many mechanics are just completely different for fair folk now.